# [Help me out..]make errors while cmake_make

Tags: make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build package with "rviz_animated_view_controller"
I set all dependencies but some make errors  occur..
I don't get why .. Please help me out....
The build result is following :

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206130/%5Bhelp-me-out..%5Dmake-errors-while-cmake_make/) by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2015-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error messages say that you have a header missing:

```
*** No rule to make target `/home/vilab/catkin_ws/src/rviz_animated_view_controller/include/rviz/animated_view_controller/rviz_animated_view_controller.h`
```

Does that file exist?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on 2015-04-01**:
Thank you I checked!